# mocking private methods to test an exported method fails in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm having an actual class like this

my-file.js

```
const methodA = () => { return 'output-from-methodA'; }

const methodB = () => { const b = methodA(); b.c = "out-put bind"; return b; }

module.exports = {
    methodB
}
```

my-file.test.js

```
const { methodA, methodB }  = require('./my-file.js');
describe('methodB testing', () => {
    it('should call methodA', () => {
        methodB();
        expect(methodA).toHaveBeenCalled()
    }
});
```

here methodA is private method, so it is not explicit to the test file, then how i ensure it is called or not in the test files

Comment: I don't know of any way to fix this without altering the module you are testing. But I do wonder: does your function have side effects? Because if your function doesn't have any side effects, then whether methodA has been called or not should not really matter, since the test should instead focus on what is returned from the function. Maybe that's a way to get around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to test the private function, only the alternative way found is to test the outputs like

```
const { methodA, methodB }  = require('./my-file.js');
describe('methodB testing', () => {
    it('should call methodA', () => {
        const result = methodB();
        expect(result.b.c).toBe("out-put bind")
    }
});
```